# Why is my laptop keyboard laggy after Ubuntu upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, dell

A few days ago I upgraded my Dell XPS 13 laptop from Ubuntu 19 to Ubuntu 20.04. Had no problems for the first few days.

Today I left my laptop temporarily and when I returned I discovered that the charger was no longer working. When I started to log in to Ubuntu I also found that the keyboard was extremely laggy. The keyboard does work but usually will not recognise a stroke unless I press firmly.

I plugged in a wireless USB keyboard and that works perfectly.  I also have had no problems with the wireless mouse. The laptops trackpad works perfectly.

I checked that the Universal Accessibility doesn't have slow keys on. I updated xserver-xorg-input-all (including reinstall).

Is there anything else I can check or should I assume maybe a power surge damaged the laptop?

Comment: Try booting a live session and compare results. If the same problem in a live session then yes, you can conclude hardware issues.

Comment: This is not a solution but a means to get more information... open a terminal and type `swappiness=0` and let us know if that made and difference.

Comment: Well, I think this is probably a driver issue but not related to Ubuntu. After my charger was destroyed I used a ThunderBolt charger from another laptop (the original wasn't ThunderBolt).  On Dell forums I found the following which led me to try pulling out the ThunderBolt cable, and then that led to my laptop keyboard being as good as normal: https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-9370-amp-TB16-USB-Keyboard-Lag-Missing-Keystrokes/td-p/6070559/page/3

Comment: @zhanmusi hi since this appears to be solved or you have found the culprit, how about updating the question to represent you have found the solution and what caused the issue for you ...

Comment: Yeah, happy to but was waiting to see if anyone would ask me to remove it first because the solution isn't really Ubuntu-related (at least as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a driver issue and not related to Ubuntu (but not entirely sure).

After my charger was destroyed I used a ThunderBolt charger from another laptop (the original wasn't ThunderBolt). On Dell forums I found the following link which led me to try pulling out the ThunderBolt cable, and then that led to my laptop keyboard being as good as normal:

https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-9370-amp-TB16-USB-Keyboard-Lag-Missing-Keystrokes/td-p/6070559/page/3

So if I am charging via Thunderbolt the keyboard is too laggy to use but an external keyboard is fine; if I stop charging via Thunderbolt then the laptop keyboard works fine.